# Azure Devops - Send alert when deploy takes long time running

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment

new Azure DevOps here
We recently did some deploys that ran for 2hs and we expected to finish them in 30min... I wonder if it's possible to configure alerts to send us emails when a deploy takes more than 30min?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider breaking own your application in to smaller components or services. 2hrs seems extreme.

You can write a small app to monitor builds using the Azure DevOps API (an Azure Function would work well), you can query for running builds (see [BuildStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildstatus)), work out the elapsed duration and alert accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0